# Domain name appended to the end of every URL as tracked in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, domains, url, tracking, url-slug

We have been tracking the content pages which are getting the traffic from different sources through Google Analytics for our website. Google Analytics append the domain URL after every content page strangely.

On our website `example.com`, content pages in Google Analytics are being tracked as:

- `/example.com` (instead of `/`)
- `/men-shoes/example.com` (instead of `/mens-shoes/`)
- `/men-shoes/casuals/example.com` (instead of `/mens-shoes/casuals/`)
- `/men-shoes/sandals/example.com` (instead of `/mens-shoes/sandals/`)
- `/men-shoes/formals/example.com` (instead of `/mens-shoes/formals/`)

[image]

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: The only thing odd that I could find for your analytics setup is that you appear to be tracking a pdf download on every pageview whether or not such a download actually happens:  `ga('send', 'event', 'PDF', 'Download', 'Magazine');`   I don't think that would have anything to do with the problem in your question.

Comment: Have you got any filters in place? That would be changing the record between the report and the entry into the database.

Comment: I'm also thinking that it's probably a badly set up filter... Give us some info on that.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. We have just added the filter to track Not provide terms which does not seem working. Please see details here:
Type: Advanced

Campaign Term
(.not provided.)

Request URI
(.*)

Output - Campaign Term
np-$B1

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered the same situation.

It appears that this behaviour is affected by settings in:
Admin -> View Settings -> Default site (optional)

You've probably placed there your site name, and now it is appended to every url in reports, because proper use for it is alias for default page when no page parameter is set, i.e. placing there `index.html` means treating / and /index.html as the same page).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like misconfigured custom filter for the profile. In standard setup, the home page is normally just /. It is a common practice to create a filter that adds the domain to the beginning to create example.com/.

Have a look at the filters (**Admin** > Select the view >  **Filters**) and see if there is anything like this setup:

[image]

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en

If the variables in constructor are in wrong order ($B1$A1), it would add the domain to the end of URL.